# How these different assignments are changing the output

Tags: java

```
class Feline {
public String type = "f ";
public Feline() {
    System.out.print("feline ");
}
}

public class Main extends Feline {
//public String type = "c ";   //Problem 1
public Main() {
    System.out.print("cougar ");
}
void go() {
    //String type = "d"; //Problem 2
    //type = "d ";             //Problem 3
    System.out.print(this.type + super.type + type);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().go();
}
}
```

The Output :

commenting the Problem 1, 2, 3 The output is feline cougar f f f

uncommenting the Problem 1 The output is feline cougar c f c

uncommenting the Problem 2 The output is feline cougar f f d

uncommenting the Problem 3 The output is feline cougar d d d

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What don't you understand ?

Comment: While this is an interesting technical problem to understand inheritance **do not access member variables in parent classes** This violates one of the most important principles in OOP: *information hiding*. BTW: the effect is called *member shadowing*

Answer (score 2):

Main super is `Feline`, because of the `extend`.

- With Problem 1, you change `this.type` and `type`, in this case they are the same, but you don't change the `super.type`, it still is the one defined in `Feline`.
- With Problem 2 and 3, you are changing a **local** variable only, not changing **super** or **public** `type`.
- With Problem 2 commented and Problem 3 not commented, you are changing the **public** `type` variable because you are not declaring a **local** variable, you are not doing `String type`.